# Как поместить результат команды в переменную?

Tags: c++

Только начал изучать С++

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main(){
   
   char d = system("ipconfig");
  // printf(d);

}
```

Я выполняю системную команду ipconfig и таким образом пытаюсь поместить результат команды в переменную, но что то мне подсказывает, что это работает не так. Подскажите как это можно сделать?

Comment: Еще и в один `char`... Вам для простоты - пишите в файл `system("ipconfig > filename")`, а потом читайте. Или смотрите `popen` (правда, это не стандарт)...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/478898/how-do-i-execute-a-command-and-get-the-output-of-the-command-within-c-using-po

Comment: В винде [_popen](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/popen-wpopen?view=msvc-160)

Comment: Пользоваться консолю именно так не есть хорошо. Можно с pipe'ами поиграться. У Linux есть API, как и у Windows.